# Setting up a table using tabulate

Tags: python, file

I have a txt file for several people in a form

```
[Name1, age1, height1]
[Name2, age2, height2]
etc.
```

I want to read the file and append line to a table.

```
f = open('my_file.txt','r')
table=[]
for line in f:
table.append(line)

a = tabulate(table,headers=["name","age","height"])
```

That doesn't work. I believe the problem is that after I append all the lines I get

```
table = ["[Name1, age1, height1]\n", "[Name2, age2, height2]\n", etc.],
```

while I want it to be

```
table = [[Name1, age1, height1], [Name2, age2, height2], etc.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop over the file object and use `ast.literal_eval` within a list comprehension to convert your lines to list objects :

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('my_file.txt','r') as f:
     table = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]
```

Note that since using `literal_eval` may raise `SyntaxError` or `ValueError`for invalid line formats like `Name1, age1, height1]` you can use a try_except to handle such cases:

```
with open('my_file.txt','r') as f:
     table = []       
     for line in f:
        try:
            table.append[literal_eval(line)]
        except (SyntaxError,ValueError):
            # do stuff
```

Also note that as a more pythonic way for dealing with file objects you better to use `with` statement which will close the file automatically at the end of the block.

Comment: No need to read all the lines. Just do `[literal_eval(line) for line in f]`

Comment: @dawg Yep, indeed, that part was remained from last update which I thought that there is no need to `literal_eval` and OP wants to get the whole of lines in a list.Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: This also assumes that the lines of the file are of the type `"['Name1', 'age1', 'height1']"` and not of the type `"[Name1, age1, height1]"` (i.e., with the individual list elements in quotes) or you will get a `ValueError`. Otherwise -- great answer

Comment: @dawg Yep, I was going to give a solution for handling that with a simple `try-except` expression.Also I think it will raise `SyntaxError` for an invalid case.

Comment: It is actually `ValueError: malformed string` for `literal_eval('[Name1, age1, height1]')`

Comment: @dawg That's because of that op has added the `Name1`, `age1`, `height1` as instance.and this name are not defined when you evaluate the list. It would be something like `'name', 24, 183]`

Comment: But there is no telling what is inside the OP's file. It could easily be unquoted strings.

Comment: @dawg Yes, it can raise both exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> table = [line.rstrip('\n')[1:-1].split(',') for line in open('file')]
>>> table
[['Name1', ' age1', ' height1'], ['Name2', ' age2', ' height2']]
```

Comment: I would do `[line.strip()[1:-1].split(',') for line in open('file')]` which takes care of all whitespace including the `\n`